# Own implementation of linear regression does not give correct results

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pytorch

I want to implement a linear regression model in pytorch, using scikit-learn's as a comparison to verify if the model created in pytroch is correct. However, the results from scikit-learn and pytroch do not match. I should be able to derive the weights of the linear regression model by using [the normal equation](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/deep-learning-with/9781789534092/2a0becca-474a-4a5e-a498-d8e254fa66f7.xhtml), but it does not work. What should I do?

self-made code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


x1 = np.round(np.linspace(0.005, 1, 500-1),4)
x2 = np.round(np.linspace(0, 1, 500), 4)
X = np.array(np.meshgrid(x1, x2)).T.reshape(-1, 2)
y = np.sin(X[:,0]) * np.sin(X[:,1]) + np.sin(X[:,0]*2) * np.sin(X[:,1]*5) + np.sin(X[:,0])

X = torch.tensor(X)
y = torch.tensor(y)

degree = 20
X = (torch.stack([ ( X[:,0]**(max-i) ) * ( X[:,1]**(i) ) for max in range(0,degree + 1) for i in range(max + 1) ], dim=1) )

X_transpose = torch.transpose(X, 0, 1)
X_transpose_X = torch.matmul(X_transpose, X)
X_transpose_X_inv = torch.inverse(X_transpose_X)
X_transpose_y = torch.matmul(X_transpose, y)
theta = torch.matmul(X_transpose_X_inv, X_transpose_y)
y_pred = torch.matmul(X, theta)
y_pred
```

Code using scikit-learn:

```
x1 = np.round(np.linspace(0.005, 1, 500-1),4)
x2 = np.round(np.linspace(0, 1, 500), 4)
X = np.array(np.meshgrid(x1, x2)).T.reshape(-1, 2)
y = np.sin(X[:,0]) * np.sin(X[:,1]) + np.sin(X[:,0]*2) * np.sin(X[:,1]*5) + np.sin(X[:,0])

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)
X_poly = poly.fit_transform(X)
X_test_poly = poly.transform(X)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_poly, y)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_poly)
y_pred
```

Comparison of results:
self-made: `tensor([ 0.0046,  0.0047,  0.0049,  ..., -4.3449, -4.3590, -4.3730], dtype=torch.float64)`
scikit-learn: `array([0.00499998, 0.00510998, 0.00521996, ..., 0.67078883, 0.67415062, 0.67759703])`
y (True value): `array([0.00499998, 0.00510998, 0.00521996, ..., 0.67078883, 0.67415062, 0.67759703])`
It does not match the value of y at all when using my own code. What should I do?